# How to manage many to one relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to make a many to one relationship and want to be able to control it (add -remove etc) via the admin panel. So this is my model.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Province(models.Model):
    numberPlate = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office)
```

I want my model allow  a province to have several Office.

So inside my admin.py:

```
class ProvinceCreator(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_filter = ['numberPlate']
        list_display = ['name', 'numberPlate','office']

class OfficeCreator(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ['name']
```

This seems correct to me, however when I try to add a new province with the admin panel, I get this:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/haritaapp/province/

Caught an exception while rendering: no such column: haritaapp_province.office_id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seams that you have your models setup *backwards*. If you want province to have many offices, then province should be a foreign key in the Office model.

```
from django.db import models

class Province(models.Model):
    numberPlate = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province)
```

This would be straightforward and very intuitive way to implement one-to-many relationsship

As for the error that you are getting "no such column: haritaapp_province.office_id", when you add a new attribute (in your case office) to the model, you should either manually add column to the table. Or drop the table and re-run the syncdb:

```
 python manage.py syncdb
```

Django will **not** automatically add new columns to the table when you add new fields to the model.

Comment: finally I could get it working, even " python manage.py syncdb" wouldn't enough so I had to delete the sqlite3 db and regen it :) One small question tho, foreign items show as Province_object while selecting/adding. How to fix it so it displays the name instead ?
Regards

Comment: oh self edit:
 def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name
did the job for me :p

Comment: in ref to "Django will not automatically add new columns" - Django-south does a good job of auto-managing model changes though I wish the migration naming scheme was more multi-dev friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the docs for doing Inlines?

In your admin.py

```
class Office(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Office

class ProvinceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        Office,
    ]
```